# Ubuntu Gnome-Shell high CPU Usage

Tags: gnome, virtualbox

I have an Ubuntu VM that has 6 out of 8 processors at 60% exec Cap.

lately I've been experiencing slow down on the VM, I looked it up and came across [This Answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1046603/how-to-find-the-cause-for-high-cpu-usage-of-gnome-shell).

This is the output of when I attached `strace` to `Gnome-Shell`'s PID:

```
ubumtu1@ubumtu1-VirtualBox:~$ sudo strace -c -p 1223
strace: Process 1223 attached
^Cstrace: Process 1223 detached
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 93.06    2.655894         168     15732       213 futex
  2.64    0.075291          34      2160           getpid
  0.92    0.026215           3      6699           poll
  0.89    0.025532           4      5915           write
  0.76    0.021766           1     13325     10932 recvmsg
  0.50    0.014290           3      3711           ioctl
  0.32    0.009057          20       445           munmap
  0.28    0.008091           3      2612           sendmsg
  0.20    0.005672           1      4246           read
  0.18    0.005264         526        10           close
  0.10    0.002994           3       898           writev
  0.07    0.001928           1      1287           epoll_wait
  0.05    0.001537           1       778           mprotect
  0.01    0.000346           4        74           mmap
  0.00    0.000062           6        10           newfstatat
  0.00    0.000060           4        14           setxattr
  0.00    0.000031           3        10           fcntl
  0.00    0.000006           1         6           getrusage
  0.00    0.000003           0         8         2 recvfrom
  0.00    0.000003           3         1           restart_syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    2.854042          49     57941     11147 total
```

I'm not sure what I'm looking for but what I understand so far is the problem comes from `futex`&`recvmsg` having high calls and errors and i'm not sure how to fix it.